# C# IF statement condition execution order (VS2010)

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have an if statement with 4 conditions:

```
if (Global.LoggedAdmin != null &&
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9 )
                 {
                   //code
                 }
```

If the column index is 5, for some reason it doesn't execude the code, with the rest of the column indexes it works, I knew that if you have a || b || c ||....|| z, if at least one of them is true, the code should execute. LoggedAdmin is always NOT null. I tried putting the column indexes conditions 1'st , and the LoggedAdmin condition last, inside the if brackets, then the code executes if column index is 5 || 6 but not when it's 9, is this normal? and if yes, why?
PS: I have another IF statement with 3 arguments that is more or less like the one above, there it failed one of the conditions ( column indexes condition ) too but when I put the column index part in brackets it worked) , for the example above, if I put them in brackets it doesn't work with any of the column indexes :/, I don't understand anything anymore.

Comment: Hint: operators precedence.

Comment: Separating terms with additional braces always worked for me: 

(a != null && (b1 || b2 || b3))

Comment: What did *you* expect `Global.LoggedAdmin != null &&` would interact with the rest of the conditions? You say that `LoggedAdmin` is always null, so presumably you expected this to be the same as `false &&`, so how did you think that was going to interact?

Comment: It is sufficient to mark an answer as accepted as you have done - there is no need to tag your question [SOLVED], as accepting an answer does exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `Global.LoggedAdmin` might actually be null and the expression evaluated is:

```
(Global.LoggedAdmin != null && LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
 ||
LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6
 ||
LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9
```

I think you might actually mean:-

```
Global.LoggedAdmin != null && (
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9)
```

which will still not execute the code since `Global.LoggedAdmin` is null.

Comment: They state in the question that `LoggedAdmin` is `null`, so I'm struggling to understand what they *thought* this statement was going to do.

Comment: @VenomXlr, Not sure if you mean `LoggedAdmin` can sometimes be null  sometimes not null, OR `LoggedAdmin` must always be not null. The evidence that when col 5 selected, the code fails to execute means either col 5 is not selected or `LoggedAdmin` is null. You decide. This is further backed by the fact that when you move the `LoggedAdmin` condition to the bottom, the code doesn't execute when col 9 is selected means that again `LoggedAdmin` is null. You should probably double check to see if `LoggedAdmin` is really null, and if you really want `LoggedAdmin != null` or `LoggedAdmin == null`

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, LoggedAdmin was actually always null,I was so  sure it is NOT null because it had to be initialised somewhere but it wasn't now the if executes as it should, sorry all for the confusion and thankyou for your time and pacience.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` has a higher precedence than the `||` operator, that's why && is evaluated first:

```
Global.LoggedAdmin != null && LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ...
```

You can see the precendences here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

That means that `Global.LoggedAdmin` is `null`, otherwise it would also be executed if the index is 5. You either have to use also `||` instead of `&&`:

```
if (Global.LoggedAdmin != null ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9 )
 {
   //code
 }
```

or you need to use `==` null and wrap the rest in round brackets. If `LoggedAdmin` is always null as you've mentioned that could make sense:

```
if (Global.LoggedAdmin == null && (
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9 ))
 {
   //code
 }
```

**Update**:

> LoggedAdmin is always NOT null, I made a error there in writing that

Than this might be code for you:

```
if (Global.LoggedAdmin != null && (
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9 ))
 {
   //code
 }
```

Comment: Please read the answer I added, LoggedAdmin is always NOT null, I made a error there in writing that.

Comment: @VenomXLR: your question still contains _"LoggedAdmin is always null"_

Comment: @VenomXLR: however, than you just have to change `== null` to `!= null` but keep the parenthesis, edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has in principle already been answered multiple times, but I`d still add a little detail for clarity, both for you, and for anybody else who might read your code later:

You can think of your if-clause as doing two tests: One for whether or not `Global.LoggedAdmin != null`, and another for whether `ColumnIndex` is one of your specified values.

For clarity, you could split this as follows; as a result, your initial problem would also disapear:

```
if (Global.LoggedAdmin != null && IsRelevantColumn())
{
    //code
}


private static bool IsRelevantColumn(){
    return LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ||
           LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 ||
           LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**As you know, Parenthesis will have higher priority.**

```
if (Global.LoggedAdmin != null &&
        LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ||
        LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 ||
        LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9 )
                     {
                       //code
                     }
```

is equivalent to

```
if ((Global.LoggedAdmin != null) &&
    (LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 ||
    LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9) )
                 {
                   //code
                 }
```

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Micheal.yes && has higher precedence than that of ||

Comment: I think so, too. And that's why I think: (a && b || c || d) is not equivalent to ((a) && (b || c || d)) but is equivalent to ((a && b) || c || d) - or do I understand you wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that `Global.LoggedAdmin` is **always** `null`. Then you have to do something like that :

```
if (Global.LoggedAdmin == null &&
LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ||
LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 ||
LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9 )
{
   //code
}
```

Or, you may do something like that :

```
if (Global.LoggedAdmin == null &&
(LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 ||
LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6 ||
LaunchDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 9 ))
{
   //code
}
```